# Wordpress custom Query for Posts in Category display posts multiple times

Tags: posts, customization, query, categories

i'm facing a problem with my custom query and need your help.

I want to display all posts of a specific category and I find this snippet:

```
// get all the categories from the database
    $cats = get_categories(); 
    // loop through the categries
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        // setup the cateogory ID
        $cat_id= 0;
        // Make a header for the cateogry
        // create a custom wordpress query
        query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=22");
        // start the wordpress loop!
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

This is working fine BUT if a posts is in more then one category then all other posts are displayed 2 and 3 times.

For Example:
I want to list all Post of Category 0
There are 2 Posts - post 1 and post 2; post 1 is also in the category 1
Post 1 and Post 2 will be displayed twice in the frontend.

How can i fix this issue?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Don't use `query_posts()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)** - it breaks things.

There's no need to run a query for each category when you can create a single query to snag posts in any specified category simultaneously. This is both more efficient as well as a means to see you don't end up with duplicates.

Since you were using `query_posts()` to replace the main query, the correct solution then is to modify the main query in a [`pre_get_posts` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook - or completely replace it with a [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) instance of your own design. In particular, you'll need to use the [category parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) - most likely `category__in` which allows you to specify an array of category ids.

All that in mind, your code doesn't make much sense - it obtains a list of every category, then queries the same category `0` as many times as there different categories. I.e., if there are 6 different categories, then that code queries category `0` for posts 6 times instead of querying each unique category.

Further, if you want to query every existing category for posts, there's no reason to include category query arguments at all - in omitting category query arguments, WordPress will perform a query for posts in any category.

Answer (score 0):

By putting the `query_posts` (and the nested `while (have_posts())` loop) inside your for loop, you are rerunning the loop and actually wrecking the main query, it's stated in the documentation for `query_posts` that you should look for any other way to modify the main loop.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

You'd get better results using an action hook for the get_posts call and adjust the `tax_query`

```
function wpse257739_custom_categories_posts( $q ) {
  if ( $q->is_main_query() ) {
    $q->set( 'tax_query', array(
      'taxonomy' => 'category',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array( 'category-one', 'category-2' ),
      'operator' => 'IN' // redundant
    ) );
  }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse257739_custom_categories_posts` );
```

Full documentation details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters